# How to store result of a select statement into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried with the below code:

```
DECLARE @rec_count     int
Set @rec_count=  select 1
```

but it shows error

> "Incorrect syntax near Select".

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you trying to store a single, scalar value from a single row (i.e. row count)? Or are you trying to store multiple columns and/or rows? The answer for each of those  questions is different, and so far, people have only been answering related to a single, scalar value. So, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

Either:

```
set @rec_count =  (select 1)
```

or

```
select @rec_count = 1
```

An example assigning the count from a table to variable:

```
set @rec_count = (select COUNT(*) from master..spt_values)
select @rec_count = COUNT(*) from master..spt_values
```

However, if you just want to assign a value to a variable you don't need any select statement:

```
set @rec_count = 1
```

or

```
declare @rec_count int = 1
```

Comment: Could you please elborate what is spt_values?

Comment: @user3868487 It's a system table; it's not really important, I just used it as an example - it could be any table or whatever you want to assign.

Answer (score 0):

To store the result of a `select` statement into a variable, see below

```
DECLARE @rec_count  INT
SELECT @rec_count = 1
```

We can get more than one value from select statement as below

```
DECLARE @rec_count  INT
DECLARE @date DATETIME

SELECT @rec_count = 1, @date = GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a record count, which looks like what you're trying to do, you can do this:

```
declare @rec_count int
select @rec_count = count(1) from [your_table] -- where some condition is met
```

**Note:** Use `count(1)` instead of `count(*)` as it's quicker to simply select a single column than all when getting a count.

Or if this count is the result of some inserts/updates/selects/deletes, you can use the [@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187316.aspx), which:

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

So if for example you are performing an `update` or `select` and want to know how many rows were affected, it will automatically be stored by SQL Server in the `@@ROWCOUNT`.

```
declare @rec_count int

-- some table change
update your_table
set col1 = 1
where col1 = 0

set @rec_count = @@ROWCOUNT
-- select @@ROWCOUNT <-- this would return the number of rows updated
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @rec_count int;
Set @rec_count = 1;
```

Comment: _How to store result of a select statement into a variable?_ This answer does not use any select statement.

Comment: It corrects the syntax error.  SELECT is not needed to set the value of the variable to 1.

Comment: The question title says "results of a select statement"

Comment: It's called an XY issue:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TabAlleman Not necessarily, the OP may have just shown us a simplified version of his query for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @TabAlleman While I agree that select is not needed to assign the variable the value, that is not what the OP is asking. It might be an XY issue, but it might also not be.

Comment: Occam's Razor.   I surely wouldn't downvote a useful answer that does solve the issue just because it isn't the answer that most closely adheres to the subject line.

Comment: @TabAlleman Neither would I, and I don't get why anyone downvotes a correct answer either, but voters vote in mysterious ways...